# Doctrine - sql to query builder with multiple joins

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have three tables. I successfully wrote sql query so and returned expected result:

```
SELECT
TM.MEMBER_ID
,R.NAME
,RA.ACTION
FROM TEAM_MEMBER TM
INNER JOIN ROLE R ON TM.TEAM_ID = R.TEAM_ID
INNER JOIN ROLE_ACTION RA ON R.ID = RA.ROLE_ID
```

The result is:

| member_id | name | abilities |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ROLE_MEMBER | read |
|  |  | create |
|  |  | edit |

As this will not be a big table with a lot of data and I am using Symfony for my project I would like to write this query using DQL.

I will post the relations between entities:

**Team Member entity**:

```
<many-to-one field="member" target-entity="Member" fetch="LAZY" inversed-by="workspaceMembers">
  <join-columns>
    <join-column name="member_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
  </join-columns>
</many-to-one>
<many-to-many field="teamMemberRoles" target-entity="Role" mapped-by="workspaceMember" fetch="LAZY"/>
```

**Role entity:**

```
<many-to-one field="team" target-entity="Team" fetch="LAZY">
        <join-columns>
            <join-column name="team_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
        </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>
    <one-to-many field="roleAbilities" target-entity="RoleAbility" mapped-by="role" />
```

**Role Ability entity:**

```
<many-to-one field="role" target-entity="Role" inversed-by="roles" fetch="LAZY">
        <join-columns>
            <join-column name="role_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
        </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>
```

Using Doctrine query builder got me confused. I tried like:

```
    $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('tm')
        ->from('App:WorkspaceMember', 'wm')
        ->innerJoin('wm.teamMemberRoles', 'r')
        ->innerJoin('r.roleAbilities', 'ra')
        ->where('wm.workspace = :teamId')
        ->andWhere('r.role = :id')
        ->andWhere('ra.ability = :roleId')
        ->setParameters([
              ////
        ]);
```

Can someone help, I am new with Doctrine and I got stuck on this one.
I defined my entity relations but thought it would be easier for me to write it in SQL first.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you did NOT define your join relations in your entities, this might help you out.
I am not sure how you defined `ROLE` and `ROLE_ACTION`, but it should get you a step further.

```php
$this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('wm')
    ->from('App:WorkspaceMember', 'wm')
    ->join('App:Roles', 'r', Join::WITH, 'wm.team_id = r.team_id')
    ->join('App:Abilities', 'ra', Join::WITH, 'r.id = ra.role_id')
    ->where('wm.workspace = :teamId')
    ->andWhere('r.role = :id')
    ->andWhere('ra.ability = :roleId')
    ->setParameters([
          ////
    ]);
```

Comment: Hi @GuidoFaecke , thank you for the replay. I have relations between my entities. But I thought that it is better to first write it in SQL. If my relations are defined, does the example you gave me needs to change?

Comment: It depend on how the relation looks like. If it is different to what you are trying to archive above, just go ahead with the code example I provided. If not, ... you might want to post your entity definitions and we can take a look at them.

Comment: Hey @GuidoFaecke , I updated the post and added part of the entities where relations are defined..
Basically I have member_id and I want to return it's roles with it's abilities..